# Search Facebook events by location

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am planning to use FB API to access "Events". For an example if I select Sri Lanka. All events by that location. If you guys had any luck with that let me know. I am browsing trough FQL to get this done didn't have much luck.

This does look like something helpful , i found it from  a search , but couldn't. Get it to work as I need. 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=post&geo=id&lang=indonesia&location=indonesia

Please post me up if you guys have any idea.

PS : Final outcome it to grab Events from FB and post on a blog something similar to tumblr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done much work on Facebook platform but the following information might help you:

Read the [Developer Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) as it will tell you how to use API methods and what are their limitations

From what I understand, you can use https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=[a valid access token] to get events that the current user has been invited to or hosting. It is important to understand that this information are per user basis and each user will have to authorize your application to use information about their subscribed events. This means that it may not be possible to do something like 'Get a list of all events taking place in Colombo, Sri Lanka'. However you could use the above mentioned api method to collect data from users who use your application. You can then use this data retrospectively create a graph showing all public events information.

Hope that helps.

Dinesh.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for the direction and instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't support searching for events by location from the API. However you can use the graph search like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=srilanka&type=event` this will search for events having "srilanka" in either the description or the name or as their location. This does not guarantee that the events are from sri lanka but you can filter out the results based on the "location" field returned by the api.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=srilanka&type=event
This is work for me, But this URL gives limited data, i want more data of public event with this query.

Any idea?